# Why is my async function being executed before an earlier promise is being fulfilled?

Tags: javascript

I've written a small program that compares the fulfillment of promises between the `.then()` approach and the `async/await` approach. The code runs correctly, however, the output was received in an unexpected order. Can someone please explain why the output is in its current order?

```js
const backend = (num) => {
  const someVar = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (num % 2 === 0) {
      resolve(`The number, ${num}, is even.`);
    } else {
      reject(`The number, ${num}, is odd.`);
    }
  })
  return someVar;
}
const builtInFuncs = (num) => {
  backend(num)
    .then(message => console.log(message))
    .catch(message => console.log(message));
}
const asyncAwait = async(num) => {
  try {
    const response = await backend(num);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

builtInFuncs(2);
builtInFuncs(3);

asyncAwait(4);
asyncAwait(5);
```

The output I expected is:

```
The number, 2, is even.
The number, 3, is odd.
The number, 4, is even.
The number, 5, is odd.
```

The output I receive is:

```
The number, 2, is even.
The number, 4, is even.
The number, 5, is odd.
The number, 3, is odd.
```

Comment: I suspect resolution has higher priority in the event queue than rejection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For microtask resolution, each method call is queued separately. So the order of execution is this:

- First call enqueued
- Second call enqueued
- Third call enqueued
- Forth call enqueued
- First `.then` fires, console.logged.
- Second `.then` fires, rejection, `.catch` handler *enqueued* (NOT called).
- Call in async/await, console.logged
- Second call to async/await, rejection, catch block enqueued.
- The `.catch` resolves, console.logged.
- The catch block resolves, final log.

Props to Barmar in the comments about the idea of switching the order of the catch and then.

To illustrate a little more simply (clearly?), consider a counter and a Promise function that increments and then decrements it:

```
let i = 0;
const log = Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => console.log(++i))
  .then(() => console.log(--i));

log();
log();
```

This will print 1 2 1 0 instead of 1 0 1 0. And if you think about it, this makes a certain amount of sense: the method chain might fail at any step so the runtime enqueues the first call and the second `.then` only gets enqueued once the first finishes. Otherwise if the first call failed (rejected) it would have to go back and delete the speculatively enqueued second call from the callback queue.

Comment: You can demonstrate this by swapping the order to: `.catch(...).then(...)`

Comment: But there's no way to reorder `try/catch` analogously.

Comment: @Barmar I updated with an example based on your suggestion.

Comment: @JaredSmith I think the catch block of the try and catch won't be enqueued. when the const response = await backend(num); the catch block will run because it's not a call to an asynchronous function it is a synchronous block of code now that the await returned (resolved or rejected). That is why the output is 2, 4, 5, 3, and not 2, 4, 3, 5.

Comment: @MostafaAmin no, async/await does not block, it's just sugar over Promises. You can test this yourself by having multiple async calls running concurrently.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks, but I didn't mean that the `async/await` blocks the code. What I meant to say was the `try/catch` block of code is not asynchronous (it won't enqueue an object to run the catch block) and that if the promise is fulfilled the try block of code will be executed and if the promise is not fulfilled (enqueues onRejected to run the catch of the promise) that will cause the catch block of code of the `try/catch` to execute. **@virtuoso actually shows what I mean in detailed steps**

Answer (score 2):

Before we get to the answer, it is worth mentioning that relying on the order of execution of asynchronous calls is not a good practice. There are two ways to achieve your expected behavior. The preferred method should be:

```
(async() => {
   await builtInFuncs(2);
   await builtInFuncs(3);
   await asyncAwait(4);
   await asyncAwait(5);
})();
```

Alternatively, you may rely on the execution order of PromiseReactionJobs guaranteed by ECMAScript Standard. You need to redefine builtInFuncs as:

```
const builtInFuncs = (num) => {
   backend(num).then(
      message => console.log(message),
      message => console.log(message)
   );
}
```

Note that both onFulfilled and onRejected handlers are passed to .then() function.

The actual reason for the observed sequence of execution is pretty involved but here is what happens:

1. `builtInFuncs(2)` gets invoked
2. `builtInFuncs(2)` invokes `backend(2).then()`
3. `backend(2).then()` in effect enqueues `console.log(2)`
4. `backend(2).then()` returns a `promise` (say `promise1`)
5. `backend(2).then().catch()` notes the `onRejected` handler on `promise1` object
6. `builtInFuncs(3)` gets invoked
7. `builtInFuncs(3)` invokes `backend(3).then()`
8. `backend(3).then()` enqueues a dummy `onRejected` handler bacause none is specified
9. `backend(3).then()` returns a `promise` (say `promise2`)
10. `backend(3).then().catch()` notes the `onRejected` handler that calls
    `console.log(3)` on `promise2`
11. `asyncAwait(4)` gets invoked
12. `asyncAwait(4)` *effectively* invokes `backend(4).then()`
13. `backend(4).then()` enqueues a onFulfilled handler that continues try branch
14. `asyncAwait(5)` gets invoked
15. `asyncAwait(5)` *effectively* invokes `backend(5).then()`
16. `backend(5).then()` enqueues a onRejected handler that continues catch branch
17. handler that prints `console.log(2)` gets dequeued
18. dummy `onRejected` handler gets dequeued
19. `promise2` enqueues `onRejected` handler it noted which prints `console.log(3)`
20. onFulfilled handler that continues try branch gets dequeued
21. onRejected handler that continues catch branch gets dequeued
22. handler that prints `console.log(3)` gets dequeued

Note that the `promise` that `backend` returns is immediately resolved or rejected. If not, there are more steps involved but effectively the same behavior is observed.